# Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedMessageEOFException: JMSCC0065: An attempt was made to read beyond the end of the message

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I'm trying to read message from WebSphere MQ, and i keep getting the below exception. Can someone please help me why this exception occurs, and the right way to read a message .

```
public String readMessage() throws JMSException {

    String message = null;
    Message msg = getJmsTemplate().receive(getGetQueue());
    if (msg instanceof BytesMessage) {
        message = ((BytesMessage) msg).readUTF();
    }
    System.out.println("from readMessage() method" + message);
    return message;
}
```

Can someone help me convert the data read by calling recieve() into String.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the exception, but if the message is a `TextMessage`...

```
String message = (String) template.receiveAndConvert(queue);
```

...if it's a `BytesMessage`...

```
String message = new String((byte[]) template.receiveAndConvert(queue));
```